# WebSockets chat app is creating new session every time I send a message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, client-server, spring-websocket

Building a chat app using spring boot and websockets. This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello WebSocket</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript><h2 style="color: #ff0000">Seems your browser doesn't support Javascript! WebSocket relies on Javascript being
    enabled. Please enable
    Javascript and reload this page!</h2></noscript>
<div id="main-content" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="connect">WebSocket connection:</label>
                    <button id="connect" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Connect</button>
                    <button id="disconnect" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" disabled="disabled">Disconnect</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">What is your message?</label>
                    <input type="text" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message here...">
                </div>
                <button id="send" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table id="conversation" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Welcome</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="welcome">
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    // Create a WebSocket connection to the server

    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

        const socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/messageHandler');

        socket.onmessage = function (event) {
            const message = event.data;
            // Handle the received message here
            console.log("Received message from server: " + message);

            // Create a new row and cell for the conversation
            const newRow = conversation.insertRow();
            const newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);

            // Set cell content to the received message
            newCell.innerText = message;
        };

        socket.onopen = function (event) {

            const sendButton = document.getElementById('send');
            const conversation = document.getElementById('conversation');

            sendButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const messageInput = document.getElementById('message');
                const message = messageInput.value;
                socket.send(message);

                
            });
        }
    });



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It should send the message to MessageHandler.java

```
package com.coursework.chatter;

import org.springframework.web.socket.*;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketMessage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MessageHandler implements WebSocketHandler {

    private static final List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connected");
        sessions.add(session);
        //System.out.println(sessions);

    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
        String messageContent = message.getPayload().toString();
        System.out.println("Received message from session " + session.getId() + ": " + messageContent);

        // Create a new WebSocketMessage containing the received message
        WebSocketMessage<String> responseMessage = new TextMessage("You sent: " + messageContent);

        // Send the response message back to the client
        session.sendMessage(responseMessage);


    }

    @Override
    public void handleTransportError(WebSocketSession session, Throwable exception) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {

//        sessions.remove(session);
//        System.out.println("Session removed"+session.getId());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsPartialMessages() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which should then send it back to the client. I set up a Handshake:

```
package com.coursework.chatter;


import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.HandshakeInterceptor;

import java.util.Map;


public class WebSocketHandshake implements HandshakeInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse, WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler, Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("No Handshake");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterHandshake(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse, WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler, Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Hand shaken");
    }
}
```

And configure the websocket

```
package com.coursework.chatter;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocket;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.server.standard.ServletServerContainerFactoryBean;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.coursework.chatter"})
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("Inside registerWebSocketHandlers :");
        registry.addHandler(messageHandler(), "/messageHandler")
                .addInterceptors(new WebSocketHandshake())
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");

    }

    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(8192);
        container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(8192);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler messageHandler() {
        return new MessageHandler();
    }


}
```

And then when I connect to the socket i get

No Handshake
Hand shaken
Connected

And then when I send messages I get:

No Handshake
Hand shaken
Connected
Received message from session 5420578e-897f-38e1-d264-6eb4cee23a0b: ahh
No Handshake
Hand shaken
Connected
Received message from session 6051a43a-ca73-68c6-3c71-3162f09a361b: lajf
No Handshake
Hand shaken
Connected

So it's receiving a message from a new session everytime but I don't understand why please help x